# Poetry: Specify 64-bit Python

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have a poetry project, that has a dependency on `tablaeuhyperapi`. We recently found out that although most of our project works fine with both 32-bit and 64-bit python, `tableauhyperapi` breaks with 32-bit Python.

Is there a way to specify that consumers need to use `64-bit python` in the `pyproject.toml` file?

Sample file that works with 64-bit python, but not 32:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "sample-project"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "Sample project that runs on 64-bit python, but not 32-bit python"
authors = ["pchaddha"]
license = "MIT Standard Licence"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.7.1,<3.10"
pandas = "^1.2.3"
pytest = "^6.2.2"
tableauhyperapi = "0.0.12366"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Looking at the poetry docs, there is some advanced dependency specifications.

Example - black:

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies.black]
version = "19.10b0"
allow-prereleases = true
python = "^3.6"
markers = "platform_python_implementation == 'CPython'"
```

Is there any way to specify python bit version in poetry? If not, what other methods can we use to ensure that consumer venv is created using 64-bit python?

Comment: I know this will happen much later than you would like, but you can check `sys.version` and fail at startup if that reports a 32-bit version of Python.

Comment: I don't think you can really prevent the installation in a specific environment (for a specific CPU bitness in your example). Normally I would recommend setting the correct trove classifiers to at least hint at the supported environments. But there does not seem to be classifiers for CPU bitness. https://pypi.org/classifiers/